# boostrap menu active page dont show style

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

So I want the active page to use same settings as the hover settings. No matter how I change the css I cant get it to work... long time since I've worked on this page tho so I might be missing some easy shit...

Style.css before changes

```
.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
    color: #fff;
    border-left:solid;
    border-right:solid;
    border-top:none;
    border-bottom:none;
    border-color:#202020;
    border-width:0.1pt;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover,
  .navbar-default .navbar-brand:focus {
    color: #fff;
    border-left:solid;
    border-right:solid;
    border-top:none;
    border-bottom:none;
    border-color:#707070;
    border-width:0.1pt;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(112, 112, 112, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(112, 112, 112, 1) 0%, #404040 20%);
  }
  .navbar-default {
    font-size: 14px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(112, 112, 112, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(112, 112, 112, 1) 0%, #202020 20%);
    border-width: 0px;
    border-radius: 0px;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(112, 112, 112, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(112, 112, 112, 1) 0%, #202020 20%);
    border-left:none;
    border-right:solid;
    border-top:none;
    border-bottom:none;
    border-color:#202020;
    border-width:0.1pt;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(112, 112, 112, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(112, 112, 112, 1) 0%, #404040 20%);
    border-left:solid;
    border-right:solid;
    border-top:none;
    border-bottom:none;
    border-color:#707070;
    border-width:0.1pt;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: rgba(231, 231, 231, 1);
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
    border-color: #ddd;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
  .navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
    background-color: #ddd;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
    background-color: #888;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover .icon-bar,
  .navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus .icon-bar {
    background-color: #000000;
  }
.navbar-default .navbar-right>li>a {
  border-left:solid;
border-width:0.1pt;
border-color:#202020;
}
```

Menu

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a href="index.php" class="navbar-brand">Per Källström</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#">Comming soon</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Comming soon</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.php" class="active">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="admin.php">Admin</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are indeed missing some easy shit, the `li` will have the `.active` class, so add this to all your hover effects: `.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li.active>a`

Comment: @LuukSkeur Thanks, however changed it slightly cuz i wanted the a as active not li :D navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a.active

Comment: No problem, cheers. Please accept my comment (as answer) and close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your HTML code. `a` tag has active class. So then it should be `.navbar-default .navbar-nav>a.active,` instead of `.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a`.

**Important Note**

whereas, bootstrap states that active class should be toggle on `li` element not on `a` tag. Please have look to following link to get right HTML. 
https://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar/

**eg:**

```
<li class="active"><a href="contact.php" >Contact</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Now as an answer:
You are indeed missing some easy shit, the `li` will have the `.active` class, so add this to all your hover effects: `.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li.active>a`